# How to call an object in Process A from Process B?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, webserver, ipc, python-multiprocessing

I have a Python web server that implements HTTPServer and uses ForkingMixIn interface to fork each request into a new process. Each request will be handled on a separate process. A BaseHTTPRequestHandler is used to handle each request. The main server (parent) runs on it's own process.

Let's say there is Server process (111), Request process (222), Request process (333).

From the Server's process (111), how can I call an object's method that lives in Request process (222) or Request process (333)?

Comment: If each request is handled in its own process, why would server process need to call into a request process?  If this is really necessary, then you could pass request info over IPC (queue, shared object, etc.). Request process would need to be waiting/checking for it to arrive over IPC and be able to return a response back over IPC.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Would going the IPC route be the only way to achieve this? Do you know any good examples/references on how to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Do you really need to fork separate processes? An alternative approach might be to use coroutines with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: @codeshark You can use queues, pipes, shared memory, but more importantly you should carefully examine why your server process would need to call a function in the request handler process. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes and https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues